# Registering all repositories and services on Unity IoC

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have an C#/asp.net mvc application and I'm trying to implement an IoC with MS Unity. My application has some `Services` that depends from `Repositories` that depends from `ISessionFactory` of NHibernate. My IoC works fine but my application is growing up and I don't wanna to register each service and repository on the container, so I would like to know how can I do it automatically? Is there any way to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: [It's pretty simple to do yourself](http://geekswithblogs.net/watsonjon/archive/2009/09/28/unity-convention-based-registration.aspx) by just using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [UnityConfiguration](https://github.com/thedersen/UnityConfiguration) extension (also available from NuGet).  It allows some "convention-based" mappings,a nd I think you can set up custom rules to register mappigns automatically.